How do I rerun function without overlap instances in javascript?
So I want to rerun my function with updated values based on an event function.
Because i'm trying to use this javascript as a content-script, while statements don't work as they just spam outputs and crash the page.
No if statements as it will just go through the code before the event and not repeat the if statement after I trigger the event. Here is basically what I'm trying to do.
function outer(value) {
  function inner() {
     outer(value); //rerun the function
     //then cancel this instance of the function
  
  }
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  //call function based off of evennt
  inner()
  }
}

I've tried all the ways to exit functions, but things like setInterval count as functions, so if I have a if statement be checked in intervals, it will only exit the setInterval.

What do you want to update in this function?
If you want to do something different in the keydown event, just delete inner and remove the eventListener at the right time.
ex:
var count = 0 // for example
function outer(value) {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleEvent)
}

function handleEvent(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  //call function based off of evennt
  count++
  removeKeyDown()
}

function removeKeyDown(){
  if (count > 3) { // just for remove
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEvent)
  }
}
  


function outer(value) {
 function inner() {
  console.log("Function rerun with value:", value);
 }
function handleEvent(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    inner();
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEvent);
    listener if you want to stop after one execution
  }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleEvent);
}
outer(42);


It looks like you're nearly there!) One thing that might be beneficial is to be mindful of how you're adding and removing event listeners. Rather than nesting too many functions or repeatedly calling outer, consider handling the logic within a single function or refactoring to avoid recursion. Here’s a more straightforward approach.
You can manage the event listener externally and control it with conditions on when to stop.
function outer(value) {
  function handleEvent(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      console.log("Function rerun with value:", value);
      // You can add more logic here if needed
      removeListener();  // Remove after use, if needed
    }
  }
  
  function removeListener() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEvent);
  }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleEvent);
}

outer(42);

This is how you might avoid repeatedly attaching the event listener and make it easier to control when the function should execute. I hope you find this helpful.
